# SAS SQL Left join based on conditions without removing rows in table A

Tags: sql, sas, left-join

I have 2 tables and want to left join table B to A based on particular criteria

The join is based on 'ID' (a.ID = b.ID) but I want to only bring in 2 columns 'status_date' and 'flag_y' from table B if b.status_date >= a.date

**Table A:**

```
+------------+-----+--------+
|    date    | ID  | Flag_x |
+------------+-----+--------+
| 01/03/2019 | 100 | x      |
| 01/03/2019 | 101 | x      |
| 02/03/2019 | 102 | x      |
| 02/03/2019 | 103 | x      |
+------------+-----+--------+
```

**Table B:**

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
| status_date | field_x | Flag_y |
+-------------+---------+--------+
| 15/03/2019  |     100 | y      |
| 10/01/2019  |     102 | y      |
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

**Desired output:**

```
+------------+-----+--------+-------------+--------+
|    date    | ID  | Flag_x | status_date | Flag_y |
+------------+-----+--------+-------------+--------+
| 01/03/2019 | 100 | x      | 15/03/2019  | y      |
| 01/03/2019 | 101 | x      |             |        |
| 02/03/2019 | 102 | x      |             |        |
| 02/03/2019 | 103 | x      |             |        |
+------------+-----+--------+-------------+--------+
```

**The code** I've tried below removes the line for ID 102 in this case where I want to keep this line but not bring in the information from table B as 'status_date' is before 'date' in table A. I assume needing to add something in the where clause???

```
PROC SQL;
Create Table Output As 
Select
a.*
,b.status_date
,b.flag_y

From Table_A as a
Left join Table_B as b
On b.ID = a.ID

Where b.status_date is Null or b.status_date >= a.date

;QUIT;
```

Hopefully this makes sense and someone can assist

Comment: You should add the date filter to the join clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```
SELECT 
  a.*
  ,b.status_date
  ,b.flag_y
FROM 
   Table_A as a
 LEFT JOIN Table_B as b
   ON b.ID = a.ID
   AND b.status_date >= a.date
```

Comment: So it was simple as that! I'm a tad confused as when attempting something very similar in SAS Hadoop it does not like the date condition. Anyway that'll be another question to be asked